# How to limit power going into a resistive load originally connected to AC mains

Tags: power-electronics, mains

I want to use the excess solar panel energy production in a home installation in electric purely resistive heating. I have the means to measure excess solar power and feed that information into a controller.

The heating element has a rated power in the 2000W ballpark and the utility can track the power transit into and out of the installation with enough precision to measure instantaneous power in and out of the installation. Therefore, a TRIAC based solution gives more instantaneous power on some parts of the cycle than the available excess power produced by the solar panels or cuts a lot of the available power during most of the cycle if the priority is to never output more than the excess power.

As an alternative, I started looking into using multiple winding transformers so I could step down the voltage and control how much power is going to the heating element in discrete steps. Before even searching for multiple winding transformers, I looked into regular double wound transformers for the 2000W rating but I found they weigh around 10kg and was looking at something a bit lighter.

I am familiar with the design of electronic and embedded circuits, but my knowledge is a bit lacking in power electronics. Given these constraints of never giving more power to the heating element instantaneously than the excess power output by the solar panels and having a somewhat light system, should I be looking at building/acquiring a full blown PWM AC-DC converter or am I overlooking other simpler solutions?

Comment: Why don't you energize the heating element with DC from the solar panels? Then you can use simple PWM control. Also, make sure you don't burn down your house. Seriously.

Comment: I am using several plug in micro inverters, one per panel, instead of a series of solar panels plus a big inverter. While a sound suggestion, it is not very pratical in this case to power the heating element directly.

Comment: Given your constraints then probably the easiest would be to rectify the combined AC output from all the micro-inverters and then use that DC to PWM your heater element.

Comment: Yeah, with micro-inverters the DC approach is... more complicated. AC is better. There must be off-the-shelf controllers for heating elements, though. Industrial controls.

Answer (score 0):

You state, "the utility can track the power transit into and out of the installation." If that is the case, then you have two serious problems:

1. If the photovoltaic array is connected to the power line through an inverter, then any change you make could endanger others working on the power lines. In addition, your installation must be in phase with the AC mains, or you might actually *draw power from the mains*, possibly destroying your equipment and/or your house.
2. If the photovoltaic array is *not* connected to the power line, yet the electric utility is being informed of power generated, e.g. through an RF-connected power meter, it seems you would be guilty of fraud, since the utility provides a rebate based on the amount generated, but power is *not* being returned to the grid.

There are electrical codes in every area for good reason. Hire someone **licensed** to interpret those codes to make the changes you want, *if the changes are feasible*.

Comment: The OP states he's using inverters.  Any modern inverter already takes #1 into account, non-issue. I do not even see how #2 is even possible, at least in North America.

Comment: As @Aaron said, #1 is not a problem, using inverters. #2 Maybe I should clarify that by saying I can feed the excess solar production information into a controller, I meant that I can use that information to control the circuit that powers the heating element. There is no comms between the installation and utility other than the utility assigned meter.